# What is the best way to integrate angular 6 in asp .net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, visual-studio, typescript

I want to upgrade my project from angular 1 to angular 6. I have developed my application in ASP.NET MVC. I know that angular 6 is completely different from angular 1. I have searched for developing  ASP.NET MVC application using angular 2 but I did not find any suitable answer. Is it possible to write and execute angular 6 (Typescript) code in visual studio?

Comment: Has you try .NET Core 2.1.? The new update has a template in Angular 5. The only thing you must do is create a new Angular 6 app and replace the ClientApp by the create with angular-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fair warning, upgrading an AngularJS project to Angular 6 is going to be a chore. As you mentioned, a lot of changes took place in the transition from AngularJS to Angular 2. Angular does have a guide for how to do the upgrade on their website:

https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

I would recommend following that guide to upgrade from Angularjs to Angular 2 first. Once you have that done, then I would continue upgrading in major version increments (that is what the Angular developers recommend for a large version upgrade). This site can help you with the rest of the upgrade process:

https://update.angular.io/

This probably goes with out saying, but when doing upgrades like this, version control software is your friend. Make sure you can always get back to a working version of your code.

Also, Microsoft maintains a starter template for an single page application with an angular front end and an ASP.Net MVC backend. You can spin up a copy of the template from the dotnet cli with the command:

```
dotnet new angular -o my-new-app
```

The template doesn't currently use the most recent version of angular, but It could be a good reference while going through the initial upgrade process. If you are starting a new project, you could use this template and then follow the guides above to upgrade to angular 6. Here is Microsoft's documentation on the template:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

Finally, if you aren't familiar with the most recent versions of angular, I would recommend perusing the rest of the angular documentation to see what is different and how things work in the most recent version. Their documentation is really good, and it could help give you a sense of where you are headed during the upgrade process.

Hope that helps. Good luck.